# using async and await with a for loop for a long process

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a sequence of code which generates videos from images using ffmpeg. I have the following code block

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

const userProject = {
    //some process data
}


async function test() {
    for (let i = 0; i < userProject.projectImages.length; i++) {
        console.log('Before await for ', i);

       //code block 1...
        let outFile = 'userGeneratedVideo/video-' + i + '.mkv';

        //code block 2
            }
            console.log('Success: Video rendering completed for: ' + outFile);

        });

        let result = await Promise.resolve(i);
        console.log('Video creation started After await. Value is ', result);
    }
}
test().then(_ => console.log('After test() resolved'));
```

The idea is to process all the images into videos and then concat the videos togather. I am having issues with my sequence, currently my output comes like this:

```
Before await for  0
Video creation started After await. Value is  0
Before await for  1
Video creation started After await. Value is  1
Before await for  2
Video creation started After await. Value is  2
Before await for  3
Video creation started After await. Value is  3
After test() resolved
Success: Video rendering completed for: userGeneratedVideo/video-2.mkv
Success: Video rendering completed for: userGeneratedVideo/video-3.mkv
Success: Video rendering completed for: userGeneratedVideo/video-0.mkv
Success: Video rendering completed for: userGeneratedVideo/video-1.mkv
```

What I am unable to figure out is how to ensure "after test() resolved" is only executed once all success: video rendering is completed.

Comment: It's unclear what your real code looks like. The code you've posted has syntax and indentation problems, likely because you removed relevant pieces of it. Promises were incorrectly chained, so you have wrong control flow.

Comment: Actually there are no promises in between. Its just one big code block of execFile which does not return any promises. My problem is with the test.then statement which should execute last but it is being executed before the success: rendering completed console.log.

Comment: Please update your code snipped, this isn't clear, I suppose you are calling in each loop something like: `renderVideo` without await, or possiblely, `renderVideo` does not return a promise.

Comment: You didn't provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , which is required by SO rules . The problem is execFile and you deliberately removed it from the question. The code you posted doesn't contain asynchronous code and will work as expected. *Actually there are no promises in between* - that's why it behaves like it behaves. There's nothing to await.

Comment: You should try `ffmpeg-concat` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-concat

Answer (score 0):

after the for loop or you can do this by using checking

```
if(i === userProject.projectImages.length -1 )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your code, because when you use `let result = await Promise.resolve(i);` really you don't wait for anything, `Promise.resolve()` is instantaneous and your real process for `await` syntax is before when you rendering the video.

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting for `i` thats is a number already resolved (not a promise), I think you has problems with `execFile` thats not return a Promise, you can do something like that:

*Supposing you are using `child_process.execFile`:*

Try:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

const userProject = {
    //some process data
}


function test() {
    return Promise.mapSeries(userProject.projectImages, (image, i) =>
        console.log('Before await for ', i);

        let outFile = 'userGeneratedVideo/video-' + i + '.mkv';

        // Supposed call
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            execFile(`ffmpeg -i ${image} -o ${outFile}`, (err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                return resolve(result);
            });
            console.log('Video creation started');
        });

    }
}
test().then(_ => console.log('After test() resolved'));
```